# Bibtext - citation with multiple author and page numbers

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am trying to give multiple citations with page numbers like

```
(Stallings, 2010, p.324; Tanenbaum, 2009, pp.17-18)
```

The best method seems to me in latex is:

```
[1, p. 324; 2, pp. 17-18]
```

I can do only the result of this:

```
\cite[p. 324]{stallings2010}, \cite[pp. 17--18]{tanenbaum2009}
```

but it gives

```
[1, p. 324], [2, pp. 17-18]
```

Is there any other and better possibility? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{AISB2008}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{AISB2008}
\bibliography{aisb}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have to use another citing style.  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: May the document class files for AISB2008 be downloaded from http://www.aisb.org.uk/convention/aisb08/download.html, or should one use a different source?

Answer (score 1):

You could load the [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/) package and use that package's `\citealp` macro as follows:

```
[\citealp[p.~324]{stallings2010}; \citealp[pp.~17--18]{tanenbaum2009}]
```

[image]

To achieve this look, you should load the `natbib` package with the options `square` and `numbers`.